# Turning sentences into yes/no questions

Tags: grammar, verbs, questions

How can I turn these sentences into yes/no questions?

```
(a) Sally ate a sandwich .
(b) Sally and the president wanted and ate a sandwich .
(c) the president sighed .
(d) the president thought that a sandwich sighed .
(e) it perplexed the president that a sandwich ate Sally .
(f) the very very very perplexed president ate a sandwich .
(g) the president worked on every proposal on the desk .
(h) Sally is lazy .
(i) Sally is eating a sandwich .
(j) the president thought that sally is a sandwich .
(k) the president thought that a sandwich sighed .
```

These are my answers. I'd love to get a review and corrections (if there are any) please:

```
(a) Did Sally eat a sandwich ?
(b) Did Sally and the president want and eat a sandwich ?
(c) Did the president sigh ?
(d) Did the president think that a sandwich sigh ?
(e) Did it perplex the president that a sandwich eat Sally ?
(f) Did the very very very perplexed president eat a sandwich ?
(g) Did the president work on every proposal on the desk ?
(h) Is Sally lazy ?
(i) Is Sally eating a sandwich ?
(j) Did the president think that sally is a sandwich ?
(k) Did president think that a sandwich sigh ?
```

Thanks!

Comment: What concern do you have?  It is a bad question if you just put your answers and say "please check these".  Why do you not think that they are all correct? What is your specific doubt?

Answer (score 1):

d) should be

> Did the president think that a sandwich sighed?

When you turn a sentence into a question like this, only the predicate verb ("think") gets converted into its base form. "sighed" is the part of the dependent clause and stays in its original form.

Likewise, e) and k) should be

> Did it perplex the president that a sandwich ate Sally?

> Did the president think that a sandwich sighed?

for the same reason.

Otherwise, the conversions are correct. However, the original sentence b) probably contains a mistake. The correct form for it is:

> Sally and the president wanted to eat a sandwich.

And as a question:

> Did Sally and the president want to eat a sandwich?

And in j), as the independent clause is in the past, the dependent should be too (sequence of tenses). So:

> The president thought that Sally was a sandwich.

> Did the president think that Sally was a sandwich?

Comment: The sentence in b is correct, considering that is given, what will be its yes/no question?

Comment: @Dan798 If we presume the sentence in b is correct, then its question form that you wrote is also correct: there is no more mistakes there.

Comment: Can you please describe why you said that sentence b is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For the questions themselves, some are grammatically wrong, (b) should be

> (b) Sally and the president wanted **to eat** a sandwich.

and the corresponding question form is

> (b) Did Sally and the president want to eat a sandwich?

If you do not want to change the sentence, then your answer for (b) is correct.

Your answer for (k) is also wrong, it should be

> (k) Did president think that a sandwich sigh**ed** ?

Your answer for (e) is also wrong, it should be

> (e) Did it perplex the president that a sandwich **ate** Sally?

Comment: The sentence in b is correct, considering that is given, what will be its yes/no question?

Comment: If you do not want to change the sentence question, then your answer for (b) is correct. @Dan798

Comment: Can you please describe why you said that sentence b is wrong?

Comment: @Dan798 We usually say "someone wants something" a 's' is being used here, you use "want", so a "to" has to be added

Comment: But is it impossible to say that someone wanted and also ate?